# How to change the format of NestJS controller/class-validator error messages showing which field each message belongs to?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, nestjs, backend, class-validator

The NestJS controller, along with the class-validator, currently returns an error message like this:

```
{
  statusCode: 422,
  message: [ 'Name is required', 'Email is required' ],
  error: 'Unprocessable Entity'
}
```

But I would like to bind each message to its related property like this:

```
{
  statusCode: 422,
  message: { name: 'Name is required', email: 'Email is required' },
  error: 'Unprocessable Entity'
}
```

My DTO:

```
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateUserRequestDTO {
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Name is required' })
  name: string;

  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Email is required' })
  email: string;
}
```

How could I change the NestJS controller/class-validator errors to return messages like this?

Answer (score 6):

The response for validation errors can be modified by passing `exceptionFactory` to the ValidationPipe options.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

See example implementation:

```js
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    exceptionFactory: (errors) => {
      return new UnprocessableEntityException({
        statusCode: 422,
        error: 'Unprocessable Entity',
        message: errors.reduce(
          (acc, e) => ({
            ...acc,
            [e.property]: Object.values(e.constraints),
          }),
          {},
        ),
      });
    },
  }),
);
```